# Search set of keywords in all files and folders and then list details in excel file using python

Tags: python

How  to show found keyword in a particular path in a drive (which should search all files ,folders,subfolders in it)
and it's found line numbers( for that particular set of keywords) in a set form like `[{keyword1, found line nosin this file (line no1, line no2,...line no. n),(it's Total found count),Kewword2, (line no1, ,line no2,...line no.,(it's Total found count) ]`

and then need to write it this data in a excel file with column headings `keyword,count,found line nos` with their `found file names` in it.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

That is apretty broad question mate with a lot of variables e.g, what kind of files are you searching as different files are opened differently e.g a `.txt` file compared to a `.docx` file.With that said, here is a simple function that will work for any plain text file, assuming i understood correctly:

```
import os
import glob

def search_words(keyword,target_dir):
    files = glob.glob(target_dir+'/**', recursive=True)
    python_files = []
    results = []
    line_no = []
    #Isolate target files from folders and everything else
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.py'):
            python_files.append(f)

    for pyf in python_files:
        with open(pyf,'rb') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
        for i,line in enumerate(lines):
            line = str(line)
            if line.find(keyword) > -1:
                line_no.append(i)

        results.append({'keyword':keyword,'lines':line_no,'target_file':pyf,'total_found':len(line_no)})
    return results
```

You could then, tweak this to accept more than one keyword,etc

Comment: also errror invalid identifier in first line itself.

Comment: also above code should write in a excel file this statics in different columns like keyword,found in these many files with their file names also the line number in each file where it found it and finally total count ( total no. of times it was found) of each keyword.

Comment: Python experts,could you  please advise here with some good code examples soon.

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: And clarify your question a bit

Comment: Version is python 3.6 and script needs to read excel file which has let's say column A having these set of keywords let' s say 100 such keywords in this column and after reading these keywords from this column 'A' python script should search them to a particular path in D drive for all folders and subfolders containing miscellaneous file types(.xml,.txt,.html,.yml,.sh...etc.)

Comment: and once match is found lets say for first keyword it finds a match in particular file at specific line number in this file and again it finds the same keyword in another file at some other line number

Comment: so here totally it was found 2 times and at different line nos in different files but it may also be the scenario that same keyword in same file is found more than once on same line no itself or at different line no as well in the same file. So we need finally this statics for this keyword :- 1) File names where it was found 2) At what lines ( it may be repeated more than one line nos as it may depend on the frequency of that particular keyword how many times it's occuring in a single file itself ) in these files it was found. 3)

Comment: Total count of that particular keyword where all it was found while searching all the file in given disk drive for all the files,folders,subfolders in it.

Comment: also after reading this excel file it should write the found these details :-1)Keyword matching file names 2) All the line nos where all it was found with their file names 3) Total count for each keyword which were found different no. of times while searching in this D drive( which has different types of files in it) for all the files,folders,subfolders in it.

Comment: This doesn't qualify as a 'question' anymore mate..its a whole project

Comment: ok,let it be anything but experts if you could please help with correct code to achieve this requirement then it would be nice.

Comment: what file types are you searching for e.g .txt, .py and i'll look into it

Comment: As stated earlier in this question script should be able to search all type of files like .txt,.yml,.xml,.html,.sh ...etc. in all the folders and subfolders for that given path in system's D drive and then finally be able to append the count column which has total counts for all the corresponding found keywords from this excel (Here let's say  Column 'A' in this excel  has all these keywords in it) so against column A it should list count and in next column it should list files where it found these key words and in next column it should list file names with the line nos for the found keyword.

Comment: ok forget about writing in excel how to achieve it in html file itself?

Comment: senior python experts could you please advise here.

Comment: are there any senior experts python to look in to this issue and help on the same please?

Comment: why am i getting negative -3 here?

Comment: this forum is to ask technically difficulyt questions only right? so same i did but did not receive any satisfactory answer by none of experts till now.

Comment: though till now 54 people have viewed but none dared to accept this challenge to answer this query in python yet.

Comment: Your question is not being answered because, it has a lot of holes, for example, If, as you say, it should check **all filetypes**. How then, do you deal with types like .mp4, .png, .mp3, .zip in the folders mentioned?You need to have a specific problem to get solutions otherwise hire a freelancer , no one wants to spend hours answering an SO questions just to get SOP

Comment: Tried below piece of code this one also not giving correct line no.

Comment: #importing required packages
 
import glob
from collections import Counter
import re
import xlwt
from xlwt import Workbook
import xlsxwriter 
import xlrd 
import errno
import time
from datetime import datetime
import datetime
import os
import os.path
import warnings
from xlutils.copy import copy
import openpyxl
 
# opening excel file
 
from xlrd import open_workbook
 
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
 
# path where all the folders and sub folders need to be searched.

Comment: how to paste code of 100 lines here. as due to characters limit unable to post the code which is not working as expected,any idea for the same please?